# javax.persistence.loadgraph with subquery goes wrong in Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, jpa-2.1

I am trying to get into JPA 2.1 EntityGraphs using Hibernate 4.3.6.Final and I encountered an issue that seems odd to me. I came across a query that results in an exception during query translation. The relevant part of my test case is the following snippet:

```
// Create the entity graph
EntityGraph<A> graph = entityManager.createEntityGraph(A.class);
graph.addSubgraph("bs", B.class);

// Perform a query that requires a subquery
entityManager.createQuery("SELECT a FROM A a WHERE NOT a.bs IS EMPTY").setHint("javax.persistence.loadgraph", graph).getResultList();
```

I am using the following entities:

```
@Entity
public class A {
    @Id
    private int id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "a")
    private Set<B> bs;
}

@Entity
public class B {
    @Id
    private int id;

    @ManyToOne
    private A a;
}
```

If I leave out the WHERE clause everything seems to work nicely.
The exception stack trace I see is:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: bs of: com.example.entities.B [SELECT a FROM com.example.entities.A a WHERE NOT a.bs IS EMPTY]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1750)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1677)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:458)
    at com.example.BugTest.testEntityGraphsAreNotAppliedToSubqueries(BugTest.java:42)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:160)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:74)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:202)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:65)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
    Caused by: org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: bs of: com.example.entities.B [SELECT a FROM com.example.entities.A a WHERE NOT a.bs IS EMPTY]
    at org.hibernate.QueryException.generateQueryException(QueryException.java:137)
    at org.hibernate.QueryException.wrapWithQueryString(QueryException.java:120)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:234)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:158)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:93)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:568)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:449)
    ... 29 more
    Caused by: org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: bs of: com.example.entities.B
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractPropertyMapping.propertyException(AbstractPropertyMapping.java:83)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractPropertyMapping.toType(AbstractPropertyMapping.java:77)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.toType(AbstractEntityPersister.java:1978)
    at org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister.toType(AbstractCollectionPersister.java:1601)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromElementType.getPropertyType(FromElementType.java:367)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromElement.getPropertyType(FromElement.java:500)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.EntityGraphQueryHint.getFromElements(EntityGraphQueryHint.java:95)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.EntityGraphQueryHint.toFromElements(EntityGraphQueryHint.java:68)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.HqlSqlWalker.processQuery(HqlSqlWalker.java:676)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.query(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:665)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.collectionFunctionOrSubselect(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:4905)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.comparisonExpr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:4606)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.logicalExpr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:2104)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.logicalExpr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:2079)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.logicalExpr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:2079)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.whereClause(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:796)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.query(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:597)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectStatement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:301)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.statement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:249)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.analyze(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:278)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:206)
    ... 34 more
```

Am I misusing the feature or am I facing an issue during Hibernate query translation?

For a quick reproduction of the issue I also set up a [small example at github](https://github.com/dajudge/hibernate-entitygraph-issue) that demonstrates the issue in a test case.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: For the record: I filed a JIRA issue at hibernate for this. It can be found at https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-9374